# Refreshing an Oracle APEX Report Region automatically after specified interval

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

How do I refreshing an oracle APEX report region automatically after a specified interval.  I tried to the following as a Function and Global Variable Declaration

```
setInterval("jQuery('##""******** WORK SAFE AND HAVE A GREAT DAY ********""#').trigger('apexrefresh');", 10000);
```

my region name is ******** WORK SAFE AND HAVE A GREAT DAY ********

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this:

```
setInterval("jQuery('#<STATIC_ID_NAME>').trigger('apexrefresh');", 30000);
```

With the static id of the report region instead of the name, as Tony said.
You have too many `#`'s

Comment: Thanks.  I have it working now.  Instead of the static ID for the main region, I had to use the static ID of one of the classic reports.  The page consist of a main region that has three sub regions.  Each sub region 3 to 6 classic reports.  Thanks again for your help! I could use some help with another problem as well.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298054/how-to-insert-the-date-into-a-table-and-return-them-into-interactive-grid

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the region **name**, you use the region `ID`.  Best idea is to first set its "Static ID" under Advanced region attributes e.g. `my_region`.  Tnen refer to `#my_region` in your Javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code in reports "HEADER TEXT"

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
```

60 means seconds